# Git branch taxonomy

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I am not that much into Git, I mostly cover total basics, and I have encountered an issue on one of our projects.

Currently, we have only a **master** branch with this file taxonomy:

1. /html/

   - file.html
2. /css/

   - file.css

However, we have decided to set up a development branch and a Gulp environment. For this I have created new branch and made required adjustments. The new branch looks like this

1. /dist/

   - /html/

     - file.html
   - /css/

     - file.css
2. /src/

   - /scss/

     - file.scss
3. gulpfile.js

Sadly, during the process I haven't realized that I made such huge changes and now I have doubts about the next steps. **So my main questions are:**

1. Will commiting this new file structure on the branch affect the master?
2. When merging to master, is there going to be an issue with these files as well meaning it will probably duplicate them and I will have all folders in my project (html, css, dist, src)?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

Committing to the development branch will not affect master.

Merging the development branch into master would incorporate all changes made on the development branch into master.  Adding new folders/files is a change.  This does not "duplicate" the files per se - git keeps a single copy of any given content.  But the additional content would be added to the master branch.

Sometimes people try to "fix" that by deleting the extra folders during the merge to master.  Then the next time they have to merge master (or a line of changes that originated in master) to their development branch, they find that git tries to delete all of those things from development (and, in the best case, they get a bunch of merge conflicts that are annoying to clean up).

For this reason, it's best to think of branches as *different versions of the same content*, not different subsets of content.  Usually attempts to treat master as a subset of development indicate that you're trying to use git as a build and deployment tool, which is not really its role.  (In some simple use cases, git can be used for deployment and some people like this because they fell it's "simple"; but it's not what it's designed for, it has little flexibility, and so I don't recommend it.)

Comment: That being said, even when I move the files to subfolders, Git will still treat it only as a pointer to new location where the file is, is that right? :)

Comment: @JiriKralovec : It will only store one copy of the file content, if that's what you mean.  *That* being said, to git "move a file to a subfolder" is interpreted as "delete the file, and create a new file in the subfolder"; and that, too, will get merged back into master.